# how does the bitwise operator compare the binary in c?

Tags: c, compare, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-xor

How does the bitwise operator compare the binary?

```c
long num1 = 22; //00010110
long num2 = 21; //00010101

if ((num1 ^ num2) == 0) {
    printf("its equal\n");
    printf("%li\n", num1);
    printf("%li\n", num2);
}
else {
    printf("not equal\n");
}
    
//$> not equal
```

Does `^` XOR operator do a for loop for each bit?

Comment: Paste the code into [the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) and take a look at the actual generated assembly code.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.. did you expect the result to be equal? C doesn't compare the bits, hardware circuits do that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude great site will look it up

Comment: `XOR` operator is probably translating into a machine XOR instruction, which is then performed by hardware.

Comment: @yano no it shouldn't be equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the implementation but most processors have a `XOR` (aka `EOR`) instruction. Even 8-bit CPUs have one.

So no it doesn't loop on each bit at compiler level. Machine code instructions can process all bits in one call (also true for bitwise `or`, `and` and `not` operators).

The compiler *could* have to create a loop if the data type is wider than the register type though (if 32 bit register machine is processing 64 bit integers for instance 2 calls to `XOR` instruction will be issued, probably not worth a loop though)